# Split string and remove spaces without .select

Tags: c#, arrays, split, trim

(Limitations: System; ONLY)

I want to be able to split a string into an array and remove the spaces, I have this currently:

```
string[] split = converText.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Also `.ToArray` can't be used apparently.

But the problem is, I can't use anything other than core system methods. So how can I trim spaces from a split or array without using `.select` or other non core ways?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string[] split = 
  convertText.Split(new[]{',',' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

by adding a space to your split criteria, it will get rid of them when you have RemoveEmptyEntries.  However this will fail if there are entries with spaces in them. In which case  you could just :-

```
string[] split = 
      convertText.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 for (int index = 0; index < split.Count; index++)
 {
     split[index] = split[index].Trim();
 }
```

Comment: it kind of is based on what I know you were doing before.... this will fail if you have a string "mega ounces, blah"  because it will split inbetween mega and oucnes

Comment: There is a chance to get an empty string in the result array. And as @Keith  said, *"this will fail if there are entries with spaces in them"*.

Answer (score 0):

It should work for all cases:

```
public static class TrimHelper
{
    public static string[] SplitAndTrim(this string str, char splitChar, StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        if (str != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in str.Split(splitChar, options))
            {
                string val = item.Trim();

                if (options == StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries && val == string.Empty)
                    continue;

                result.Add(val);
            }
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string[] split = "text, ".SplitAndTrim(',').ToArray();
```